# restrict instance of object to fit certain parameters

Tags: java, design-patterns

Say I have a class pet and it is composed of two variables:

```
Class Pet {
Category category; // be amphibian, fish, mammal, dog
Diet diet; //meat, vegetarian, omnivore
...
```

If category = dog I want to restrict diet to omnivore only (and vice versa). My actual problem is somewhat more complex, whats the best way to code this ? I started with nested enums and then inner builder class ...

Is their a common pattern I can employ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this trouble because you are not taking advantage of inheritance here. `Dog` **IS A** `Pet`. So let `Dog extend Pet`. `Pet` will have abstract `setDiet()` and `Dog` will **implement this with applying the diet rules applicable for Dog**.

```
class Pet
{
  Diet diet;

  abstract boolean satisfiesDietRules();

  public Pet()
  {
    if(!satisfiesDietRules())
    {
      throw CannotCreatePetException();
    }
  }
}

class Dog extends Pet
{
  boolean satisfiesDietRules()
  {
    //rules
  }
}
```

Now, you can encapsulate the diet rules in their respective `enum` (your current approach) or leverage inheritance which is natural. If you go composition approach, then you can't leverage polymorphism. So it depends upon your business requirements to understand which one to use. If you make sure that you doesn't violate LSV then inheritance seems to be a natural solution for this.

Comment: favour composition over inheritance ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky Yes. This is a perfect candidate of inheritance. This has the least possibility of violating LSP. Issues (your post) due to the use of Composition is clearly evident in this scenario...

Comment: make pet abstract, well for my real world example that seems appropriate, or why not an interface ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky it depends upon your use case. If you think there is no common behavior then do so. But in this scenario you have to make sure that the diet rules are applied before creating the instance so abstract class is fine

Comment: ah yeah, i see, put the restrictions int he constructor on the abstract/base class. thnx

Answer (score 2):

You could have the constructor throw an exception if an attempt is made to create an instance of your class with an invalid combination of parameters.

This is assuming those attributes are immutable (as they appear to be from the context). If they are not, the setters for `diet` etc would also need to enforce the constraints.